# jQuery onscroll in wordpress not working properly

Tags: jquery, ajax, wordpress

I am sending ajax call in wordpress to load the data from the table when the user scroll down but the problem is that whole page is adding in the response when i am scrolling down . When I applied on button click the ajax call is working fine but not on scroll this is my jQuery code

```
$ = jQuery;
$(function() {
    $(window).scroll(function() {
        var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
        if (scroll >= 100) {
         var page=parseInt($(this).data('page'));
         var ajaxurl=$(this).data('url');
    jQuery.ajax({    
        url:ajaxurl,
        type:"POST",
        data:{
            page:page,
            action:"my_loadmore"
        },
        error:function(response){
          console.log("error");  
        },
        success:function(data){
          if (data !== undefined ){ 
               jQuery('button.myLoad').data('page',(page+1));
               jQuery('#left-area').append(data);
           }
           else {
               jQuery('button.myLoad').remove();
           } 
        }
    });
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: The `scroll` event fires multiple times a second on most browsers and so will the Ajax call unless you set a flag... "whole page is adding in the response" - what does that mean exactly.

Comment: @Shikkediel it returns the whole html of the page

Comment: I want to make an ajax call on every scroll down of the page

Comment: With browsers that have smooth scrolling enabled, that will be equal to the frame rate. So usually around 60 times a second... unless they use the scrollbar because then it will be even more.

Comment: can you make a solution to that problem lets suppose 80% of the page

Comment: I don't think I am able to do so with the current info provided. Try posting a full example, HTML included.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/194890/discussion-between-tayyab-gulsher-vohra-and-shikkediel).